# Transforming Features to increase similarity

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a large dataset (~20,000 samples x 2,000 features-- each sample w/ a corresponding y-value) that I'm constructing a regression ML model for.
The input vectors are bitvectors with either 1s or 0s at each position.

Interestingly, I have noticed that when I 'randomly' select N samples such that their y-values are between two arbitrary values A and B (such that B-A is much smaller than the total range of values in y), the subsequent model is much better at predicting *other* values with the A-->B range not used in the training of the model.

*However*, the overall similarity of the input X vectors for these values are in no way *more* similar than any random selection of X values across the whole dataset.

Is there an available method to transform the input X-vectors such that those with more similar y-values are "closer" (I'm not particular the methodology, but it could be something like cosine similarity), and those with not similar y-values are separated?

Answer (score 0):

After more thought, I believe this question can be re-framed as a supervised clustering problem. What might be able to accomplish this might be as simple as:

```py
import umap 

print(df.shape)
>> (23,312, 2149)

print(len(target))
>> 23,312 

embedding = umap.UMAP().fit_transform(df, y=target)
```